# Grails Data Service Cannot Use Regular Service

Tags: grails

Happy Another Covid Day. When I use generate-all, Grails creates the Data Service for me. I begin to understand what a data service is.

I also have my own service for my Author and Book classes to use. I name my service ImportService.  I have methods in the ImportService to clean up my book data read from a CSV file before the Data Service saves my books to the database. I also follow the instruction to make the Data Service an Abstract Class. So, I can put my own method in the Data Service.

Since the Author has its own AuthorService, and the Book has its own BookService,  I want the different Data Service to access the method in my ImportService.  So, I don't have to copy and paste the import CSV code multiple times.  So, I put the line **ImportService importService** in the AuthorServie class and the BookService class. That does not go well. **importService** is always NULL inside the Data Service classes.  I google the problem.  They say I cannot inject another service to the grails.gorm.services.Service.

There is a post that says to make a bean.  I am new to Grails. I have no idea what they are talking about even with the codes posted.  Part of my background is Assembly Language, C, and Pascal.  My head is filled with lingo like Top Down, Subroutine, library, Address, and Pointer.  I have no idea what a Bean is.

This is what it is.  I am wondering whether this is a bug or by design that you cannot inject a service to the gorm service.

Thanks for your "Pointer".

Comment: You haven't indicated what version of Grails or what version of GORM you are using so I don't know if this relevant or not but there was a relevant bug in GORM that we fixed recently.  See https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/202.

Comment: I am using Grails 4.0.3.  I am new to Grails.  I don't know where to look for the GORM version.  Would you show me where to get the GORM version please?  Thx!  I was using Grails 4.0.4 but it kept crashing.  Someone suggested to roll back to 4.0.3.  That's why I am using 4.0.3.

Comment: "Would you show me where to get the GORM version please?" - It is hard to say without looking at your build but the place where the GORM version by default would be specified in Grails 4.0.3 would be in the `gradle.properties` file at the top of the project.

Comment: Thx.  This is the version number.  Is this causing the problem that I cannot use a service in the data service? grailsVersion=4.0.3
gorm.version=7.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: I believe the fix is in 7.0.7.RELEASE.

Comment: Thx.  I change the line in `gradle.properties` file from `gorm.version=7.0.6 RELEASE` to `gorm.version=7.0.7 RELEASE`.  My BookService data service still cannot get the reference to my ImportService.  `ImportService importService` is NULL.  I guess I will give up on this for now.

Comment: "I guess I will give up on this for now." - Ok.  I will create a sample app and provide a link here.  Should you decide you want to pick it back up, that app should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502servicedi.  That project uses Grails 4.0.3 and GORM 7.0.7.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502servicedi/blob/main/grails-app/services/tom6502servicedi/ImportService.groovy

```
package tom6502servicedi

class ImportService {

    int getSomeNumber() {
        42
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502servicedi/blob/917c51ee173e7bb6844ca7d40ced5afbb8d9063f/grails-app/services/tom6502servicedi/AuthorService.groovy

```
package tom6502servicedi

import grails.gorm.services.Service
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

@Service(Author)
abstract class AuthorService {

    @Autowired
    ImportService importService

    // ...

    int getSomeNumberFromImportService() {
        importService.someNumber
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502servicedi/blob/917c51ee173e7bb6844ca7d40ced5afbb8d9063f/grails-app/controllers/tom6502servicedi/AuthorController.groovy

```
package tom6502servicedi

import grails.validation.ValidationException
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

class AuthorController {

    AuthorService authorService

    // ...

    def someNumber() {
        render "The Number Is ${authorService.someNumberFromImportService}"
    }
}
```

Sending a request to that `someNumber` action will verify that the `ImportService` is injected into the `AuthorService` and the `AuthorService` is injected into the `AuthorController`.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/author/someNumber
The Number Is 42
```

Comment: Wow!  This is miracle!  Totally defies the law of physic!!!  Adding **import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired** and the word **@Autowired** to the data service make Grails to get the reference to my ImportService class now.  T-H-A-N-K-S!!!